# How to pass specific values for Get-AzSubscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

We have a command to get all the subscriptions  Get-AzSubscription | Set-Azcontext and set for that to work with multiple subscription. How do we fetch specific subscriptions from Get-AzSubscription and pass it for Set-Azcontext.

In order to do that I have tried below :
I have tried something $subscription = Get-AzSubscription -TenantId "tenant id" | where-object{$_.Name -like 'required name*'}
$subscription | Set-AzContext

Is there any better way to do the same?

Regards

Deb

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for that cmdlet? The documentation should always be your starting point for questions like this.

Comment: I have tried something

$subscription = Get-AzSubscription -TenantId "tenant id" | where-object{$_.Name -like 'required name*'}
$subscription | Set-AzContext

But thinking is there is another way to do the same, that's where asks forum help.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect your actual question. At the moment the question as asked has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your method as long as:

- You can easily write the filter clause to include all the required subscriptions. If there is no consistent naming scheme you might end up with lots of `... -or ... -or ...` clauses which is messy.
- You are happy that your script will automatically start to act on any new subscriptions added to your tenancy which match your filter clause.

If however:

- You don't have good naming scheme so it's difficult to write a simple filter.
- The script must act only on the specified subscriptions.

Then you could do this:

```
$subs = @('Sub 1','Live Sub','2 Test','Deb')

$subs | get-azsubscription -SubscriptionName {$_} | set-azcontext
```

Comment: I have 100 subscriptions out of that I need 20 , how to get in Get-Azsubscription and set the value for set-azcontext

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following command to select the particular subscription you want to use :

- Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx

Comment: I have 100 subscriptions out of that I need 20 , how to get in Get-Azsubscription and set the value for set-azcontext